# How to hide background image in input textbox when populated using CSS

Tags: css, focus, hide, background-image

I have effectively use the following css style:

```
input.my-text:focus { background-image: none; }
```

It works great. But how do I continue to hide the background image when the textbox gets populated? I only want the background image to show when the textbox is blank.

I tried `:valid:` but that does not work the way I need it too.

Is this do-able in css or do I need to resort to javascript/jquery ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[How about "hacking" the placeholder functionality.](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-css3-placeholder-pseudo-element)

http://jsfiddle.net/f01g6spe/1/

```
input{
    position: relative;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    background: pink;
    display: block
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting @tribe84. How does css know there is input? I'm trying to figure that out. Does it come from `::-webkit-input-placeholder`

Comment: Yeah, it works using the CSS  3 placeholder specification. You can read about it some more here: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/02/html5-accessibility-chops-the-placeholder-attribute/

Comment: Well I tried to simplify it  to meet my needs and this did not work `input.my-text::-webkit-input-placeholder { background-image: none; }`